# What should I do when the AMI catalogue in AWS EC2 is empty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just wanted to start an EC2 instance in Amazon AWS/EC2, but the list of possible "official" AMIs to equip the instance with is empty, so is the AMI catalogue (apart from 2 old AMIs I've created myself and the "unofficial" community AMIs):

[image: Empty list in Instance creation]

[image: Empty AMI catalog]

I don't think I've done anything special: Just selected my AWS location (eu-central-1) and the instance type I wanted (t2.micro). I would have expected the page to offer me AMIs to select from (Windows, Linux, with or without extra software), but the list is empty.

Does/can the catalog depend on anything else I've configured (obviously wrong)?

Comment: What is the output of `aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-central-1`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the aws CLI tool on my machine. I use EC2 so rarely that I always use the website to launch/stop instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved it.

When you are using a javascript-blocking browser extension, make sure that none of the domains, AWS includes, is blocked. In my case, `aws.dev` was untrusted.